# Как сделать закрытие скрипта питон если введённый текст содержит заданный символ?

Tags: python

Например:
`text = "Какой-то текст.\n"`
А запрещённые символы это ".", Пробел и "\n"
Как сделать что бы вывело "В тексте содержаться запрещённые символы"?

Comment: Прочитайте, как использовать условные операторы, как проверить наличие символа в строке. Ещё можно про списки и циклы - это тоже поможет, но на старте, в общем, не обязательно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = 'Какой-то текст.\n'

bad_symbols = ('.', '\n', ' ')
for symbol in text:
    if symbol in bad_symbols:
        print('В тексте содержатся запрещённые символы')
        break
```

1. Создать список запрещенных символов
2. Пробежаться по каждому символу строки циклом for и проверить каждый символ на совпадение с содержимым списка запрещенных символов

Comment: break добавьте ещё, а то будет печататься на каждый найденный символ.

Comment: Ну и `\n` и `/n` это разные вещи

Comment: Точно! Черт его знает куда смотрел)